# How do I patch in to a file only the insertions and modifications leaving the unmodified lines there?

Tags: bash, diff, patch, database

I have a short file (around 60 lines) which acts like a basic database it has three whitespace separated columns. The first one is name of the product, the second one is the price and the third one is the qunatity.

```
product1 5 25
product2 8 30
product3 15 80
product4 2 200
```

Then I create a new file which contains some modifications in the same format

```
product1 5 45
product3 18 80
product5 5 25
```

After that I want to merge the two files into one and it should look something like this

```
product1 5 45
product2 8 30
product3 18 80
product4 2 200
product5 5 25
```

I tried using diff and patch but it removed the lines which were not present in the update file.
How should I tackle this problem?

Comment: Roughly how many lines does your real file contain?

Comment: Not that much. Around 50-60

Comment: Do the lines in the output file need to be in any particular order?

Comment: No. Only the columns have to respect the product price quantity order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your source file is `data` and your updates file is `updates` this short code will satisfy your requirement

```
awk '{ h[$1] = $0 } END { for (i in h) { print h[i] } }' data updates
```

`awk` code is split into stanzas:

```
{ h[$1] = $0 }                         # save each line, keyed by first element, overwriting as necessary
END { for (i in h) { print h[i] } }    # when we have read everything, print each element in the array
```

Comment: Thank you. Works like a charm.